# how to add last item in MvxRecyclerView with different template

Tags: android, xamarin, mvvmcross, android-recyclerview

I am developing Xamarin Android Application.I am using MvvmCross to take advantage of ViewModels.I have bind the **MvxRecyclerView** with template.I want to add last item of that **MvxRecyclerView** with different template.How to implement that ?
Any suggestion or advice will be appreciated

Comment: Don`t know if it is possible, you could add a second MvxListView just underneath with the different template and join them to make it seem like it is just one.

Comment: You could also have conditions in the layout template bound to properties  on the passed in view model and then hide or show specific UI Elements.